# Camera preview on 3D cube in openGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, camera

I'm trying to show on one of the square faces of the 3D cube a camera preview but I'm pretty new to openGL and I didnt anything useful around...
i want the camera preview to keep previewing even though if the user has rotated the cube and cant see the preview.
that my code for the cube:

```
public class TextureCube {
   private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer; // Buffer for vertex-array
   private FloatBuffer texBuffer;    // Buffer for texture-coords-array 

   private float[] vertices = { // Vertices for a face
      -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
       1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
      -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
       1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f   // 3. right-top-front
   };

   float[] texCoords = { // Texture coords for the above face
      0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom
      1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom
      0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top
      1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top
   };
   int[] textureIDs = new int[1];   // Array for 1 texture-ID (NEW)

   // Constructor - Set up the buffers
   public TextureCube() {
     ...
   }

   // Draw the shape
   public void draw(GL10 gl) {

      gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);    // Front face in counter-clockwise orientation
      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
      gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    // Cull the back face (don't display) 

      gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
      gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  // Enable texture-coords-array (NEW)
      gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define texture-coords buffer (NEW)

      // front

      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

      gl.glColor4f(colors[0][0], colors[0][1], colors[0][2], colors[0][3]);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // left
      ...

      // back
      ...

      // right
      ...

      // top
      ...

      // bottom
     ...

      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  // Disable texture-coords-array (NEW)
      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
   }

   // Load an image into GL texture
   public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: What exactly shall the "preview" be showing? What you probably want is a render-to-texture pass which is creating the preview image, and then you can just map that texture to the cube face.

Comment: i want to be able to see the live camera just like in camera preview.
i want to see it on one of the square faces

Comment: Actually, there is no "camera" in the GL, that is only a methaphor often used. But you can render whatever you want to a texture.

Comment: @derhass so how can i render the camera into one of the square faces